# familydefault ignored when sbox defined in preamble

Tags: fonts, boxes

I would like to define my global family default once in the preamble. I would also like to define my save boxes in the preamble, but somehow the latter does not seem to work with the former, as it simply ignores the family default for the text in the sbox. When The sbox is defined within \begin{document} it works fine.

So my question is: Why is this not working, and what can i do about it?

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % set default font to cmss

\newsavebox{\testbox}
\sbox{\testbox}{
    Hello World!
}

\begin{document}
    \usebox{\testbox}\\
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can add `\sffamily` before the save box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changing the macro does not change any fonts at that point, it just changes the default when a font is selected, you can for example use `\normalfont`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % set default font to cmss
\normalfont
\newsavebox{\testbox}
\sbox{\testbox}{
    Hello World!
}

\begin{document}
    \usebox{\testbox}\\
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: so in other words the font is set on definition not on use?

Comment: @cdx I'm not sure that I understand the comment, "set" and "use" probably mean the same thing in this context. `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} ` is just a macro definition defining the macro `\familydefault` it does not affect any fonts at that point. Like any `(re)newcommand` it has no effect unless the comand defined is used later. `\familydefault` is used by commands such as `\normalfont` that set the font without explicitly naming a font family.

Comment: What i meant is the following: the sbox is defined in place A and used in place B. In place A, a certain font is active, in place B its a different font. I thought the sbox would use the font of place B since it is called there. But as you pointed out it uses the font of place A where the sbox is defined (in my case the preamble). I wanted to make sure my understanding is correct, because if it is, it might be impossible to change the font used within the sbox after the sbox's definition.

Comment: @cdx a box is a typeset fragment of fixed fonts, size etc, the whole point is that it doesn't get reset when re-used.